# Windows remote connection stopped to work

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I had been using a remote connection to a specific machine for months. All of a sudden (the other day) I started getting a "Login attempt failed" error.

Image of the error (It's in portuguese, sorry):

[image]

I tested it with another machine and it worked.

I tried with this machine to connect to other stations and it worked too. So I created a new user on the target machine and it worked.

The only problem is connecting to a specific machine using a specific user (but it works when accessed from a different machine).

Any idea?

--EDIT--
I installed the Remote Desktop from Microsoft Store and it's working for the same IP and same user/password so the problem is the "old" RDP software. Is there a way to reset or something like this?

Comment: Could be an update on that machine. See if that one has gotten a recent update that the others you've tried it on haven't got yet. MS have managed to break RDP in Win10 and 11 several times in the last 6 months via updates, many of which have caused login prompt style errors.

Comment: Other machine with the same windows version is working properly so it might be something related to this credential for this machine using the old RDP client but I can't think what can be done to fix it :(